# Toggle between classes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, click

How do I add and remove a class every time I click?

**Original Code**

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
  background: blue;
}
```

I want to add:

```
.rounded {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

I know I have to use the click function on the box div, but I don't know how to add a class and remove it.

## Answer:

Use the toggleClass

```
$(".box").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("rounded");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do this. How about this approach instead...

```
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
  background: blue;
}

.box.rounded {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Then just toggle the "rounded" class with `toggleClass`.

```
$('.box').toggleClass('rounded');
```

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions are just switching between class(es). If you want to modify the existing one and add/remove values from it use this:

```
$('.box').css('border-radius','50px');
```

and to remove:

```
$('.box').css('border-radius', '');
```

**[Working example](http://codepen.io/decho/pen/hFjoD).**

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you! I can't give rep point just yet. It won't let me, but thanks again.

Comment: but you can still accept the answer by clicking 'tick' sign.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery can remove a class, however **cannot alter any CSS in class**:

```
$(target).addClass("myClass");
$(target).removeClass("myClass andThisOne removeSoManyClasses");
```

To overwrite a class the other way:

```
$("body").append("<style class='remove'>.box{/*many css*/}</style>");
$(".remove").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.
To add css class the syntax is,

```
$(selector).addClass(classname)
```

To removecss class the syntax is,

```
$(selector).removeClass(classname)
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/krishanudey/LskJZ/)